# Calendar Scheduler like control to specify value ranges

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a range mapping control like scheduler control on which x-axis has one integer value and y-axis has another and the user specifies the mappings using cell clicks and drag options.

- This is how my implementation looks like.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcf3v.jpg

I have implemented a proof of concept using html table but i was wondering if there's an open source library to achieve it. My code is as follows.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th class="w-10">
    &nbsp;
</th>
<th ng-repeat="columnHeading in ctrl.viewModel.vLeanings.columns" class="text-center w-9">                                                                
    {{columnHeading}}
</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.viewModel.vLeanings.rows">
    <th>{{row.rowNo | number:3}}</th>
    <td ng-repeat="column in row.columns" ng-mouseover="ctrl.onMouseOver(row,column);" ng-mousedown="ctrl.onMouseDown(row,column);" ng-mouseup="ctrl.onMouseUp();" ng-class="column.selected?column.imported?'label-danger':'label-primary':''">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there any open source control available for AngularJS or Javascript? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the open source project fullcalendar maintained by Adam Shaw. Having been down the road of creating a scheduling calendar before, the fullcalendar project provided me the flexibility to easily customize the project to fit my requirements. The app I used this in utilized dates and times for the x and y axis, but you can customize this to fit other values.

[FullCalendar at Github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar)

[FullCalendar Demo](https://fullcalendar.io/)

Screen shot is from application created that used fullcalendar.
[image]